# How do you allow '-' in regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to allow '-' in the regular expression for telephone numbers, but the - is usually used for ranges (e.g. A-Z). So how do I allow just the character?  I tried escapting using /-, but that's not working.

```
$reg_num = "/[^0-9+ ()]/";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape it with a backslash `\`. So it should be written as `\-`.

Answer (score 3):

Write it in the end instead of '-' being between two characters.
Very simplified example:
`[0-9-]` would match `099-2233-3333` where 0-9 is a range, and the `-` in the end is a seperate dash sign to match.

Answer (score 1):

Put it first in the range, like `[^-0-9+ ()]`. The hyphen needs to separate two characters to define a range; if it isn't (in this case because the `^` is also interpreted as a modifier, not a character in the set), then it's just a character in the set like any other.

Answer (score 0):

escaping using `\-`

```
\
```

is escape character!